# How to change text color of IcsSpinner on ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

My Action bar is currently like this:

[image]

i want it to be like this:

[image]

ignore the black line beside the logo. Mainly what i want is to `change the color of the text in the IcsSpinner to white`

my activity code is:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, cities);
    listAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
    setContentView(mViewPager);
    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
    bar.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    IcsSpinner citySpinner = (IcsSpinner) (bar.getCustomView())
            .findViewById(R.id.city_spinner);
    citySpinner.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

and my custom_actionbar.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
        android:id="@+id/city_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I even want the spinner to be `just left to the refresh icon`. Like in the second image.

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext()` as the `Context` instance given to the adapter for inflating layouts. This will use whatever theme is appropriate for inflating widgets inside the action bar rather than the theme set for the contents of your activity.

Comment: yeah that solved in changing the text color. thanks a lot. but how can i change the IcsSpinner position to right side??. like in the 2nd image

Comment: You can't change where it displays. If you need more control over something like that you have to use a custom action view.

Answer (score 1):

Just to compliment the accepted answer: this worked for me after having some weird NullPointerException while trying to create new ArrayAdapter using constructor

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(actionBar.getThemedContext(),
        R.array.action_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```